# Spring MVC - PropertyEditor not called during ModelAttribute type conversion

Tags: spring-mvc, type-conversion

Using Spring 3.2.3, I'm trying to implement a simple CRUD controller that handles REST-ful URLs. It relies on a PropertyEditor to convert a path variable to a BusinessService entity by loading it from an application service. Code is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class BusinessServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private BusinessServiceService businessSvcService;

    public BusinessServiceController() {
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(BusinessService.class, new BusinessServicePropertyEditor(businessSvcService));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ui/account/business-services/{businessSvc}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("businessSvc") @Valid final BusinessService businessSvc, final BindingResult result,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttribs) throws UnknownBusinessServiceException {
        ModelAndView mav;

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            mav = new ModelAndView("/business-service/edit");
        }
        else {
            businessSvcService.updateBusinessService(XSecurity.principal().getId(), businessSvc);

            mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/ui/account/business-services");
            redirectAttribs.addFlashAttribute("message", Message.info("businessService.updated", businessSvc.getTitle()));
        }

        return mav;
    }
}

public class BusinessServicePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    private final BusinessServiceService businessSvcService;

    public BusinessServicePropertyEditor(final BusinessServiceService businessSvcService) {
        this.businessSvcService = businessSvcService;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        final BusinessService svc = (BusinessService) getValue();
        return Long.toString(svc.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(final String text) {
        final BusinessService svc = businessSvcService.getBusinessService(Long.parseLong(text));
        setValue(svc);
    }
}
```

According to [SPR-7608](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7608), starting from Spring 3.2, @ModelAttribute method argument resolution checks if a path variable by the same name exists (it does here), in which case it tries to convert that path variable's value to the target parameter type through registered Converters and PropertyEditors. This is not what I'm experiencing. When I inspect what ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor does, it clearly uses the request DataBinder's ConversionService to perform type conversion, which does not consider registered PropertyEditors, and hence BusinessServicePropertyEditor#setAsText is never called.

Is this a configuration problem or an actual bug?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course I can store the BusinessService as a SessionAttribute when handling the GET method and retrieve it as a ModelAttribute in the POST method, but I would like to avoid using the session as much as possible. Surely this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's `ConversionService` and `Converter`s are replacement for standard Java Beans `PropertyEditor`s.

You need to implement `Converter` instead of `PropertyEditor` if this feature is based purely on conversion service.

---

To register your custom converters in `WebDataBinder` you might use `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer` or `@InitBinder` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, type conversion does work when registering a custom converter against the ConversionService. It does bother me however that there are two ways to do type conversion (PropertyEditors and Converters) and that you have to know which one to use in which case. I think I will submit a bug for this.

Comment: Spring was originally based on property editors. Some original components remain their property editor support. However all new features are converter based. Three is no bug.